IngressError: Could not flush buffer: os error 10061 No connection could be made becuase the target machine actively refused it
I get (os error 10061) when I run my python script through Anaconda on local. I've checked that the firewall is disabled. I verified questdb 2.0.3 is installed. Here is my script:
 import pandas as pd
 from questdb.ingress import Sender, TimestampNanos

 qp=pd.DataFrame({'last': [price], 'Symbol': ['NQ'], 'time':time.time()})

This is on ibkr api. The error says its on line app.run()
        conf =   f'http::addr=localhost:9000;'
        with Sender.from_conf(conf) as sender:
            sender.dataframe(qp, table_name='Nlastry', at=TimestampNanos.now())


QuestDB developer advocate here :)
Are QuestDB or Anaconda running on containers? Asking as 'localhost' might mean one thing for Anaconda and a different one for QuestDB if containers are involved. Also, can you access http://localhost:9000 and see the questdb web console?

No containers are used. It's just anaconda environment on a windows home pc. When I type that address into a browser I get the site cannot be reached, I think. I'll get the exact browser error later tonight. Thanks.

I switched it from the dataframe ingestion method to the standard string method. I had to comment out app.disconnect() at the bottom of my script. It stayed connected and made me think it was ingesting--but I can't access http://localhost:9000 and I cannot do a query. I get "Unable to connect".

If when typing http://localhost:9000 in the browser you cannot see the questdb web interface, it means either questdb is not running, the default port was overriden by config, the port is not accessible from localhost, or there is some kind of error on startup. If you cannot see the web interface, you will not be able to access from a script. I would focus on making sure questdb starts properly and you can access from the browser. Can you see anything on the QuestDB logs on startup?

I just saw that I have to start questdb by running questdb.exe or something. I guess that is why people aren't using anaconda, i don't think anaconda supports executable; although there is a questdb available in pip. I think I've solved my ballooning row and slowing time series query conundrum in sqlite by converting millisecond to integer, and setting field as primary key, so the resulting search is binary. My whole algo is in sqlite, so if this works, I'll go with it. Cheers

Sure! QuestDB is a client-server database. You need to start the database server before you run any queries or insert. In that regard it is like PostgreSQL or MySQL. SQLite is embedded, so it is a different use case. Glad you found a solution that works for you :)

I'm just kidding, I didnt use time stamp as my primary key, but I realized I can just use rowid in this situation, and it's as fast as primary key. I can't actually use time stamp, because it's not unique.
